Einstein Solid: Density of States vs. Partition Function
This question probably has a straightforward answer. The density of states in a 3D Einstein solid is
\begin{equation}
D(\varepsilon) = 3N\delta(\varepsilon-\hbar\omega_E)
\end{equation}
where $\omega_E$ is the Einstein frequency. This approach says the atoms in the solid all vibrate at the same frequency. The heat capacity becomes
\begin{align}
C_V &= 3Nk_B \bigg(\frac{1}{k_BT}\bigg)^2 \int_0^{\infty} \delta(\varepsilon-\hbar\omega_E)\frac{\varepsilon^2 e^{\varepsilon/k_BT}}{\big(e^{\varepsilon/k_BT}-1\big)^2}\text{d}\varepsilon \\
&= 3Nk_B \bigg(\frac{\hbar\omega_E}{2k_BT}\bigg)^2\text{csch}^2\bigg(\frac{\hbar\omega_E}{2k_BT}\bigg)
\end{align}
The partition function approach uses the full quantum harmonic oscillator energy spectrum
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_n = \hbar\omega_E\bigg(n + \frac{1}{2}\bigg)
\end{equation}
which produces
\begin{equation}
Z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\hbar\omega_E(n+1/2)/k_BT} = 2\text{csch}\bigg(\frac{\hbar\omega_E}{2k_BT}\bigg)
\end{equation}
With an average energy
\begin{equation}
U = -\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial\beta} = \frac{\hbar\omega_E}{2}\text{coth}\bigg(\frac{\hbar\omega_E}{2k_BT}\bigg)
\end{equation}
The heat capacity, $C_V = \partial U/\partial T$, works out to be the same as in the density of states approach. Why are the approaches equivalent when the density of states does not account for the full spectrum of quantum harmonic oscillator eigenvalues? It forces every atom into the same $\hbar\omega_E$ energy. I feel like there's something important that I'm missing here.

You are just mistaken in thinking that the density of states approach only contained $n=1$ because the fact that you have a denominator $(\mathrm e^{\varepsilon/k_BT}-1)^2$ is already the infinite ladder of QHO states.

@naturallyInconsistent That sounds like a good answer in the making.

@naturallyInconsistent So the Bose-Einstein distribution contains information on the eigenvalue structure? Why would it? Is this a universal property that applies to other systems with boson statistics? I would think that boson statistics are accounted for in the combinatorics after the Hamiltonian is specified.

Why would you expect "Bose-Einstein distribution" to not account for Bose-Einstein statistics? I don't even understand how you could have such a misconception! And you only learn Bose-Einstein after having done Maxwell-Boltzmann, which shows in exact how they differ: you could just substitute the relevant expressions and see that it doesn't have the same behaviour. And then after Bose-Einstein, you do Fermi-Dirac. You try them out, and you will quickly learn to see that the form of the equations already directly state what the statistics are.

@naturallyInconsistent In the DoS approach, I'm saying myself that phonons obey boson statistics. My point is that boson statistics care about how the particles in the system can occupy the energy states, but it has no concern for what the specific energy states are, as far as I understand it. In the partition function approach, the $(e^{\varepsilon/k_BT}-1)^2$ factor came from the $n$ in the energy spectra. I could just as well have plugged in a Hamiltonian with an $n^2$, in which case that term wouldn't have emerged, but I could say the particles still obey boson statistics all the same?

Yes and no. You are correct in saying that if the Hamiltonian had $n^2$ instead, then you will not have $(\mathrm e^{\varepsilon/k_BT}-1)^2$ in the denominator, and a lot would change. But whether it follows boson statistics or not is a different question involving how you deal with $n$, and is really independent of the Hamiltonian.

You were actually using the density of states for the 1D quantum harmonic oscillator. Setting $\hbar \omega=1$ and $\beta = \frac1{k_BT}$, for $N$, $D$-dimension, oscillators, The full partition function is:
$$
\begin{align}
Z &= \int D(E)e^{-\beta E}dE \\
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\beta(n+1/2)}\right)^{ND} \\
&= \frac{e^{-\beta ND/2}}{(1-e^{-\beta})^{ND}} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{ND+n}ne^{-\beta(n+ND/2)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, your density of states is rather:
$$
D(E) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{ND+n-1}n\delta(E-ND/2-n)
$$
You could have derived this combinatorially by splitting $n$ quantas among $ND$ oscillators. In general, the energy density of states of two independent systems is the convolution of their respective densities. This is why it is better to go to the canonical ensemble, which is just a Laplace transform, converting convolution to multiplication. A good sanity check is to smooth out the density of states to check whether you recover the classical density of states. You can now consistently compute energy and heat capacity.
